# Segue through navigationcontroller

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

[image]

So I have a button in [2] and it pushes to [3] through the Navigation Controller so I can go back to [2] with the "Back" button in the toolbar. This all works fine.

In [4] I have a button too and I want it to go to [3]. But it should also go through the navigation controller so that when I press "Back" I can return to [2] again.

So actually I want the button on [4] to go like [ 1 ][ 2 ][ 3 ] so that I can return to [2] from [3]

```
@IBAction func showKaart(sender: AnyObject) {
 performSegueWithIdentifier("menuToKaart", sender: sender)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, I believe try it.

Mind your root view controller is `vc[2]`, ok? 
You push from `vc[2]` > `vc[3]`, next press back and return to `vc[2]`, that's ok!
You push from `vc[4]` > `vc[3]`, next press back and return to `vc[4]`, but you need back to `vc[2]`?

For this logic you can create your custom behavior to `vc[3]`

For your `vc[3]` I do this to control behavior.

```
class ViewController3:UIViewController{

    var backToRoot:Bool = false;

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.hideAndAddNewBackButton();
    }

    private func hideAndAddNewBackButton(){
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
    }

    func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if backToRoot{
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewControllerAnimated(true);
        }else{
            self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
        }
    }

    func needBackToRoot(){
        backToRoot = true;
    }
}
```

Now in `vc[4]` I think you can modify the back button behavior of your `vc[3]` 
I mind two way to do with your `vc[4]`

First using performSegue.

```
class ViewController4PerfomSegue:UIViewController{

    @IBAction func pressButtonToPushViewController3(sender:AnyObject?){
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("showViewController3", sender: nil);
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if let viewController3 = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController3{
            viewController3.needBackToRoot();
        }
    }

}
```

Second with push manual in your navigation view controller

```
class ViewController4Push:UIViewController{

    @IBAction func pressButtonToPushViewController3(sender:AnyObject?){
        let viewController3 = ViewController3(nibName: "ViewController3", bundle: nil);
        viewController3.needBackToRoot();
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController3, animated: true);
    }
}
```

**Edit:** new way to instantiate from storyboard

```
class ViewController4Push:UIViewController{

    @IBAction func pressButtonToPushViewController3(sender:AnyObject?){
        if let viewController3 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as? ViewController3{
            viewController3.needBackToRoot();
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController3, animated: true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Edit:** removing when new view was presented

```
class ViewController4Push:UIViewController, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

    @IBAction func pressButtonToPushViewController3(sender:AnyObject?){
        if let viewController3 = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewController3") as? ViewController3{
            viewController3.needBackToRoot();
            self.navigationController?.delegate = self;
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController3, animated: true);
        }
    }

    func navigationController(navigationController: UINavigationController, didShowViewController viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.delegate = nil;
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(false, completion: nil);
        //or self.removeFromParentViewController();
    }
}
```

I hope help you, if I understand the problem

**Edit:** after talk in chat with Sinan we resolve it with simple way, just force back present the root element of application

```
class ViewCustomController:UIViewController{

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad();
        self.hideAndAddNewBackButton();
    }

    private func hideAndAddNewBackButton(){
        self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "back:")
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;
    }

    func back(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        if let viewControllerRoot = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("ViewControllerRoot") as? ViewControllerRoot{
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController2, animated: true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You understand it correctly. But when I do it this way it gives me this error: `Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/Sinan/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA459ED8-F4E3-49B1-8FBD-1A519B2DE0D7/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/E5F3BFFE-8D84-48AD-A4EC-0F9951FC8BE2/Ontdek Polen.app> (loaded)' with name 'Kaart''` The name of my vc[3] in my project is `Kaart`

Comment: I believe you tried second way with push. Use the way @Kevin Lau helped.. look my edit

Comment: Just like the answer of @Kelvin Lau it returns me to [4] when I press back instead of [2].

Comment: How did you add your `vc[4]` in `vc[2]`?? Did use `navigationController.push(vc[4])`?

Comment: In vc[4] I added the last piece of code in your answer. In vc[3] I added the first piece of code. You didn't say anything about vc[2].

Comment: Ok, but how case do you present `vc[4]`?? Do you add `vc[4]` in `vc[2]`, What is the moment you present `vc[4]`? and How way you show `vc[4]`, with `presentViewController` or `navigationController.push` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88805/discussion-between-vituu-and-sinan-samet).

Comment: In my project vc[2] is a menu. From vc[2] You can go to vc[3] and vc[4], and more pages. My goal is to add a button on vc[3] and vc[4] so you can switch from vc[3] to vc[4] and from vc[4] to vc[3]. When you press on "Back" it always goes to vc[2]

Answer (score 0):

[4] needs to be embedded in a navigation controller. After that, change you `@IBAction` to use `pushViewController:Animated:` on the `navigationController` instead of `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: So I need to create a new navigation controller for [4]? And I don't exactly understand how I am supposed to use `pushViewController:Animated` on the navigationController. Do I need to make a new file for the navigationcontroller and use it there? Or in the file of [4]?

Comment: `navigationController!.pushViewController(VCToPushTo, animated: true)`. But this only works if you've embedded a navigation controller to your current view controller hierarchy. [1][2][3] is a view controller hierarchy with a navigation controller.

Comment: I clicked on [4] and pressed Editor > Embed In > Navigation Controller. Now it has a navigation controller and I added the pushViewController function to it but when I press the button on [4] I still get directed to [3] without a toolbar where I can back in.

Comment: in [4], don't call `performSegueWithIdentifier:`. Call `navigationController!.pushViewController(VCToPushTo, animated: true)`

Comment: Yea I did do that. But I removed the push link from the button to [3]. But now I have it this way `self.navigationController?.pushViewController(Kaart.self, animated: true);` it gives me this error `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`. The name of the vc [3] is `Kaart` in my project. Sorry I'm new to Swift and I make stupid mistakes.

Comment: `VCToPushTo` needs to be a reference to a `UIViewController` object. In other words, `storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Kaart") as ! KartViewController`, assuming you've labeled your VC with "Kaart"

Comment: Ah I finally got it to work that way but the problem now is when I press "Back" it returns me to [4] instead of [2]

Comment: that is expected behaviour. Back button by default goes back to your previous screen.Look up unwind segues if you need to implement custom behaviours

Comment: Well this was actually the whole point. I need it to return to [2] when I press back. I'll look it up..